# Javascript onclick and escapes

Tags: javascript, jquery

If my onclick event looks like:

```
<input .... onclick="someEvent('blah', '/some/folder/?a=1')" />
```

Should the `?` character be escaped?

Answer (score 1):

For the purpose of passing the string parameter to `someEvent`, you **don't** need to escape the `?`.

How you use the parameter in the event handler is another question, though on a URL it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

In your simplified example it's fine as is. It's no different than passing it a question, ie `What is for dinner?`